# complex dimension of the two component $V^{1,0}$ and $V^{0,1}$ in $V_{\Bbb{C}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-geometry

Let $V$ be a complex vector space with $I$ as the complex structure associated with it(which is a $\Bbb{R}$ linear map).

If we pretend $V$ be a real vector space then complexified it $V_{\Bbb{C}}$ then we can extend $I$ to $V_{\Bbb{C}}$ in a natural way.Then we can decompose $$V_{\Bbb{C}} = V^{0,1}\bigoplus V^{1,0}$$

with $V^{1,0}$ the eigenspace of $I$ associated to $i$ and the other associated to $-i$.

The question is why the two summands $V^{0,1},V^{1,0}$ have same complex dimension,I know since conjugation is the real linear isomorphism when treated as real vector space,they have same dimension,the question is why they are complex isomorphic to each other?

Comment: Since real dimension of a vector space is 2 times it's complex dimension ,correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful with the complex structure you are using in $V_\mathbb{C}$, there are two possible ones: the extension of $I$ that you mentioned and the natural one as a complexification, namely multiplication by $i$: $i\cdot(v\otimes z) = v\otimes(iz)$.

$(V,I)$ is itself complex isomorphic to $(V^{1,0},i)$, but it is **not** complex isomorphic to $(V^{0,1},i)$. Now if you want to see that they have the same complex dimension you can explicitly construct bases. You start with some vector $x_1\in V$ and apply $I$ to it, $y_1:=I(x_1)$. Then you select some $x_2$ in the complement of the real span of $x_1,y_1$. You will end up with a basis for $V$ of the form $x_1,y_1=I(x_1),x_2,y_2=I(x_2),\dots,x_n,y_n=I(x_n)$. Checking that this is a linearly independent set is as easy as to apply $I$ to a linear combination of these.

Now, you can check that $\{z_i=\frac{1}{2}(x_i\otimes 1 - y_i\otimes i)\}_i$ is a basis for $V^{1,0}$ and that $\{\overline{z}_i= \frac{1}{2}(x_i\otimes 1+y_i\otimes i)\}_i$ is a basis for $V^{0,1}$. The union of those bases clearly is a basis for $V_\mathbb{C}$ and now simply check that each $z_i,\overline{z}_i$ has the corresponding $\pm i$ eigenvalue for $I$.

If you are searching for a more abstract version you can check that the parametrizations

$$j_{1,0}(v) = \frac{1}{2}(v\otimes 1 - I(v)\otimes i)\in V^{1,0}$$
$$j_{0,1}(v) = \frac{1}{2}(v\otimes 1 + I(v)\otimes i)\in V^{0,1}$$

for all $v\in V$ are real isomorphisms. The first one is complex linear $(V,I)\rightarrow (V^{1,0},i)$ and the second one is complex antilinear $(V,I)\rightarrow (V^{0,1},i)$. Showing that they are injective is easy, and for the surjectiveness you can use that $V_\mathbb{C}=V^{1,0}\oplus V^{0,1}$.

EDIT: I completely forgot about conjugation. This is a real isomorphism sending $V^{1,0}$ to $V^{0,1}$ and viceversa. Therefore they have the same real dimension as subspaces of $V_\mathbb{C}$, but as you say, the complex dimensions with respect to the ambient structure $i$ cited and the beginning of the answer must be half of the real dimensions.

Comment: Thank you,I have a question ,if $V^{0,1} $ and $V^{1,0}$ have same complex dimension ,then by the linear algebra fact we have complex linear isomorphism $V^{1,0} \to V^{0,1}$ then compose with the first one $(V,I) \to (V^{1,0},i)$ ,will get the isomorphism between $(V,I)$ and $(V^{0,1},i)$?

Comment: thank you for your help there is a slight typo here $j_{1,0}(v) = \frac{1}{2}(v - I(v))\in V^{1,0}
$ should be $j_{1,0}(v) = \frac{1}{2}(v - iI(v))\in V^{1,0}
$

Comment: Thank you for spotting the typo, I have already fixed it. 

You should be very careful about the first comment: indeed, all complex vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic, but this is not a canonical isomorphism, unless some extra structure is provided (Hilbert spaces for instance). For sure $(V,I)$ and $(V^{0,1},i)$ are isomorphic, but this isomorphism will NOT respect the embedding of $V^{0,1}$ sitting inside $(V_\mathbb{C},i)$.